# Expanding a field of repeated floats to multiple columns in a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ table X with a field named output which is of repeated float type with length=10. so, the column is sth like: [v0,... ,v9] for each row. I'd like to transform the table in a way to add 10 new columns to the table with new col_names.  Basically, I'd like to have this new table:

row0: v00, ..., v09, rest of column values for row0
row1: v10, ..., v19, rest of column values for row1
...
rown: vn1, ..., vn9, rest of column values for rown

Thanks for your help in advance!

I am aware of UNNEST function but I don't think that would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
WITH X AS
 (SELECT [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] as col1, 'Neil' as name UNION ALL
  SELECT [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19], 'Bob')

SELECT * EXCEPT(col1), col1[OFFSET(0)] as c0,
  col1[OFFSET(1)] as c1,
  col1[OFFSET(2)] as c2,
  col1[OFFSET(3)] as c3,
  col1[OFFSET(4)] as c4,
  col1[OFFSET(5)] as c5,
  col1[OFFSET(6)] as c6,
  col1[OFFSET(7)] as c7,
  col1[OFFSET(8)] as c8,
  col1[OFFSET(9)] as c9,                
 FROM X
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * except(col1)      
  from your_table, unnest(col1) val with offset
)
pivot (any_value(val) as v for offset in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

if applied to sample data (i am reusing sample from Kolban's answer) output is

[image]